# Keeping unique elements of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, unique

I have two arrays in C++ with the same length. I want to get two new arrays out f them: the first new array will have the unique elements of the first original one, while the second the corresponding values from the second original array. For example:

Original:

1st: 1 7 2 3 5 4 4 8 9 9 4 6 7

2nd: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5

and I want to get:

1st: 1 7 2 3 5 4 8 9 6

2nd: 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 5

Maybe I can use hash tables, but not quite sure how to do it. Any kind of solution is fine. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you want to keep order of elements like in original array?

Comment: How big is your array, common case? If it's like dozens of elements, you might do better just using a contiguous representation (`std::vector` or ideally one optimized to avoid the free store in such tiny cases). If it's bigger, `std::set`. Oh and what Anton said -- do you want to preserve insertion order?

Comment: With respect to the downvotes and close votes, this question could be interesting (unless it's just precisely calling for `std::set`, e.g.), but you'd have to state your requirements more explicitly. Don't be discouraged just yet -- try editing the question to make it more well-defined. Another one is the data constraints -- are they always integers? If so, within a narrow range?

Comment: thanks for responses, the order in the output is not important, the result may be ordered by the first array/vector, but the correspondance must remain: 1st: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9// 2nd: 1 1 1 2 2 5 1 3 3  is also fine. The size could up to 10000 elements. Yes, only integers in both arrays, the range is between 0 and 9999. You may use vectors too, I just picked arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches that represent fairly general types of solutions:

1. Make a single array of pairs and sort+uniquify that:

   ```
   int a[N], b[N];  // ... your data

   std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v({{a[0], b[0]}, /*...*/, {a[N-1], b[N-1]}});

   std::sort(
       v.begin(), v.end(),
       [](const auto & lhs, const auto & rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
   auto it = std::unique(
       v.begin(), v.end(),
       [](const auto & lhs, const auto & rhs) { return lhs.first == rhs.first;});
   v.erase(it, v.end());
   ```

   Now the unique values of `a` are `v[i].first` for `i` in `[0, v.size())`, and respectively the corresponding entries of `b` are `v[i].second`.
2. Sort and uniquify an array of indices via indirection:

   ```
   std::vector<std::size_t> idx({0, 1, 2, /* ... */, N - 1});

   std::sort(
       idx.begin(), idx.end(),
       [&a](std::size_t i, std::size_t j) { return a[i] < a[j]; });
   auto it = std::unique(
       v.begin(), v.end(),
       [&a](std::size_t i, std::size_t j) { return a[i] == a[j]; });
   v.erase(it, v.end());
   ```

   Now the unique values of `a` are in `a[idx[i]]` for i in `[0, v.size())`, and the corresponding values of `b` are in `b[idx[i]]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I tried to use the first version,but I get errors from my compiler (Dev-C++). The first is [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'. I am new in C++ and I don't understand the error, I tried to fix it but with no success. Could you please provide a hint how to make it run? Thanks again.

Comment: @km1234: The code uses [contemporary C++](https://ideone.com/Zc1OgJ) (C++14); if your compiler doesn't support that, you need to modify the code to its corresponding C++03 form.